# How to calculate wing upwash angle?

Tags: aerodynamics

How can I calculate upwash angle(alpha **u**) at the wing? I notice at every position upwash angle is different, which angle is chosen as the reference upwash angle?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a preliminary estimation of the upwash in front of the wing, the following plot¹ can be used:

[image: Upwash in front of a wing]

Given the distance in front of the wing (x-axis) and the aspect ratio $A$, the plot returns $\frac{\partial \epsilon_u}{\partial \alpha}$ (y-axis), where $\epsilon_u$ is the upwash angle. The value $\frac{\partial \epsilon_u}{\partial \alpha}$ from the plot has to be multiplied by the wing's AoA to get $\epsilon_u$.

---

¹from: *Daniel P. Raymer, Aircraft Design: A Conceptual Approach*; in turn taken from: *Hoak D. et al., USAF DATCOM*.

Comment: Camber line at the bottom right is contour of wing?

Comment: Yes, from 0.25 till -0.75

Comment: Where can I find how to calculate upwash angles, lifting line, lifting surface theory?

Comment: Regarding upwash any book about general airplane design contains some method to estimate it. Regarding lifting line/surface theory any book about aerodynamics contains an explanation about it.